# Learn python the hard way -- Ex 23 -- Breaking it ex 3

Tags: python

I've been working on some code that will read a textfile with hexacode and decode it but I can't figure out how to readline() without making it read it as a string.

help would be really appreciated thx :)

Been trying to solve this problem for 4 hours now without rest lol. 
Now I think it's time to look for some help :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to post a [mre] if you want help with debugging. You can [edit] the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a binary file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710456/reading-a-binary-file-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
import binascii
filename = 'test.dat'
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
print(binascii.hexlify(content))
```

Original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964245/convert-file-to-hex-string-python)

Comment: I get an error msg right now saying that utf-8 can't decode what I'm trying to decode do you think I need another encoder/ decodet than utf-8 for it to work?. It also sais invalid start byte. thx btw